# How to register an Enum class in Kryonet?

Tags: java, networking, enums, kryonet

I am trying to register my classes in order to send information over a network.  I need to register an Enum class that looks like this:

```
public enum Fort{
    NOFORT("No Fort", 0, 0), TOWER("Tower", 1, 1), KEEP("Keep", 2, 2), CASTLE("Castle", 3, 3), CITADEL("Citadel", 4, 4);

    protected int combatValue;
    protected int income;
    protected String name;

    private Fort(String n, int c, int i){
        name = n;
        combatValue = c;
        income = i;
    }

    public int getFortIncome(){
        return income;
    }
    public int getComatValue(){
        return combatValue;
    }
}
```

I am trying to send my entire game board over a network, which is requiring me to register all of the subclasses contained inside of my Board.  The main issue is that I I get stuck when trying to register my enum.

This is what I am doing in my networking class:

```
    // tell Kryo what things it's going to have to send
    private void registerClasses(Kryo kryo) {
        kryo.register(Request.class);
        kryo.register(PacketMessage.class);

        kryo.register(Fort.class);
        kryo.register(ArrayList.class);
        kryo.register(Tile.class);
        kryo.register(Board.class);
    }
```

When I try to register Fort.class I get a bunch of errors that look like this:

```
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:504)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.write(FieldSerializer.java:564)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:213)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:504)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.write(FieldSerializer.java:564)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:213)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:504)
```

Am I registering my enum incorrectly?  Any ideas on how I can do this properly?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like a Kryo question. Here is the [Kryo project](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) page.

Comment: I've been looking at it but I can't find any information on enums!  I can't be the only with this issue

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually worked with enums in kryo, but since their values can be pretty much simplified to a number (ordinal), you can write your own serializer that will do just that. I'll however look into that, it would be nice if it worked out of the box.
Btw. that stack trace is not of much use without the first line on which it says what exception was thrown.